# jQuery toggle() not working in FF3.0.12

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery code(toggel) which is working fine in IE6 but not in FF3.
what can be the reason or workaround.

```
 <button>Toggle Me</button>
  <p>Hi</p>
  <p>Learning JQuery</p>
```

Jquery:

```
 $(function() {
        $("button").click(function() {
            $("p").toggle("slow")
        });
    });
```

CSS:

```
p 
   { background:#dad;
     font-weight:bold;
     font-size:16px; 


     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be inclined to use

```
<input type="button" ID="button" value="Toggle Me" />
```

instead of

```
<button>
```

and then change your code to

```
 $(function() {
        $("#button").click(function() {
            $("p").toggle("slow");
        });
    });
```

You were missing a `;` after `toggle("slow")` which IE may forgive you for but other browsers may be less forgiving.

**[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/akone)**

Comment: input type=button is bad example, button tag is for purpose. just need to have ID.

Comment: @Thinker: I have tried <button id="button">Toggle Me</button>
but it didnt work.any clue..

Comment: <button> elements inside forms submit different values depending on the browser, therefore I tend to stick to <input> elements.

Comment: I think <button> elements are better than inputs, as in most of the cases, they don't carry any information, and can contain other HTML tags (img, strong, etc). But that's another debate :)